# Run a background task periodically in Meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, background-process

Suppose I have a small meteor app that shows cities and the their temperatures. These cities are saved in a DB.

I would like a server non blocking process that would periodically pull a web page and parse the temperatures let's say every hour for example, to update the values in the DB.

I'm assuming that as soon as the new values get updated, all the connected users would see the updated temperatures without even refreshing the page.

How do I achieve this as a Meteor beginner please. This process should be independent of the users, it should run every hour whether there has been users on the page or not.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [percolate:synced-cron](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron) package to create a cron job. Runs on the server. It can be scheduled to run with any periodicity using momentjs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use [meteor-job-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection) to do this. I've just pulled some code from my project which will give you a good starting point. Just include this file in your server code and add the parsing code to the job:

```
const parse_RATE = 1000 * 60 * 60;
const parseQueue = JobCollection('parseQueue');

parseQueue.processJobs('parse', { pollInterval: parse_RATE }, function(job, cb) {

   // Parse your web page

   <add your code here>

   // Signal that the job's done

   job.done();

   // Since .done() will create a new repeating job, we can now delete
   // this old job so that we don't fill up the database with dead ones.

   job.remove();
   cb();

});

// Remove any old jobs that were set up when the server was last running

const oldJobs = parseQueue.find();
oldJobs.forEach((job) => {
   parseQueue.cancelJobs([job._id]);
   parseQueue.removeJobs([job._id]);
});

// Create a new parse job
//
// We parse at 4am every day when the server is the least busy.

parseQueue.startJobServer();

const job = new Job(parseQueue, 'parse', {});
job.priority('normal')
   .repeat({ schedule: parseQueue.later.parse.recur().every(1).hour() })
   .save();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use my new [Steve Jobs](https://github.com/msavin/SteveJobs..meteor.jobs.scheduler.queue.background.tasks) package. It's very friendly towards the Meteor way of doing things.

Comment: Could you please explain key difference(s) with percolate:synced-cron?

Comment: @Raz think of synced-cron as something that will run one function repeatedly, at the time interval you specify. Steve Jobs is more like, running a method at a time you specify, and you can queue up as many as you want, to run whenever you want.